# Sorting by date not working?

Tags: order, server, troubleshooting

I have a blog which has worked as normal. I recently moved it to another server by cloning the database and copying all the files. Now my posts are ordered randomly. Where do I start troubleshooting?

Comment: I don't think there are any specific answers to your question. My guess here would be that your cloning process hit a ditch somewhere. I would suggest to search this site on how to clone/migrate a wordpress site.

Comment: Had you done _anything else at all_ to the data, other than making copy of database and files? Had anything, like URLs, changed?